# Why the results are different when indexing torch.Tensor with tables {1}, {{1}}?

Tags: lua, deep-learning, torch

Suppose **A** is a torch tensor of 3x10x10, why the results are different when indexing with tables {1}, {{1}} and {{{1}}}?

```
In [53]: A:size()
Out[53]: 
  3
 10
 10
[torch.LongStorage of size 3]

In [54]: A[{1}]:size()
'Out[54]: 
 10
 10
[torch.LongStorage of size 2]

In [55]: A[{{1}}]:size()
Out[55]: 
  1
 10
 10
[torch.LongStorage of size 3]

In [56]: A[{{{1}}}]:size()
Out[56]: 
  3
 10
 10
[torch.LongStorage of size 3]
```

Comment: Because you access different indices.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lua Torch7 array index notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452897/lua-torch7-array-index-notation)